# El valor de una variable solo captura el ultimo dato de un select

Tags: php, mvc, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

```
<select name="corregimiento" class="custom-select">
    <option value="nombrecorregimiento" <?= $dato="nombrecorregimiento";?>>Nombre del Corregimiento</option>
    <option value="municipio" <?= $dato="municipio";?>>Municipio</option>
</select>
                    
<td><a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="<?= base_url('formulario/buscar/' . $dato) ?>" role="button">Editar</a> </td>
```

Intento capturar el valor `nombrecorregimiento` o `municipio` pero la variable dato siempre termina capturando el valor final, en este caso `municipio`.

¿De que manera puedo hacer que capture cualquier dato del `select` sin que cambie su valor por el ultimo dato del `select`?.

Comment: Tienes errores de sintaxis dentro del php en el que al parecer quieres asignar el atributo **dato** a las opciones. esta expresión `<?=$ dato="nombrecorregimiento" ;?>` y la análoga para municipio seguramente no hacen lo que esperas. Adicionalmente, si `$dato` es una variable no debe tener espacio intermedio. Por favor revisa el código.

Comment: @quevedo el error de sintaxis fue agregado en [una edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/431096/1) por otro usuario.

Comment: ¿Quisieras que al cambiar el valor del `select`, el `href` cambiara tomando el valor de la opción seleccionada? Si es eso, podrías hacerlo con `Javascript`, te interesa?

Comment: Deseo pasar el un campo de select e input al controlador para hacer un buscador, y no el código originalmente no deja un espacio entre el $ y dato, aun continuo con el mismo problema y conozco muy poco de javascript.

Comment: Al ejecutar el código que muestras se obtiene esto en el navegador `<select name="corregimiento" class="custom-select">
    <option value="nombrecorregimiento" nombrecorregimiento>Nombre del Corregimiento</option>
    <option value="municipio" municipio>Municipio</option>` la razón es que `<?=` opera como `<?php echo` y asignas la variable, de modo que se genera un atributo sin valor explícito dentro de la etiqueta. Necesitas corregir el código o indicarnos qué tratas de hacer allí para poder ayudarte. **Lo ejecuté en opera y copié el código html generado**